# Multiple AJAX requests on a page efficiency

Tags: php, ajax

I have an application of which loads around 5 sections of data using AJAX.

I find that on load of the application, sometimes (1 in 8) one or more of the sections hang and sometimes does not complete.

The AJAX requests are POST/AJAX requests and populate div containers with the associated php/html from the server.

They are not too bulky.

I was wondering why this might be happening? Is there a more efficient way of handling multiple AJAX calls? Perhaps ordering them? Do they perhaps cause issue with the server if multiple requests are sent at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Todays browsers only send 12 requests per domain. After that, they wait for a request to finish before issuing another one.

This means if you want 5 AJAX calls simultanously execute, there is only room for 7 more request. If you have images and other ressources (js/css) on your page from the same domain, this can get an issue.

This also explains why it does not happen everytime. Your browser may have some other ressources in cache and skips the requests, leaving room for your AJAX calls.